# Python numpy: create 2d array of values based on coordinates

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a file containing 3 columns, where the first two are coordinates (x,y) and the third is a value (z) corresponding to that position. Here's a short example:

```
x y z
0 1 14
0 2 17
1 0 15
1 1 16
2 1 18
2 2 13
```

I want to create a 2D array of values from the third row based on their x,y coordinates in the file. I read in each column as an individual array, and I created grids of x values and y values using numpy.meshgrid, like this:

```
x = [[0 1 2]    and   y = [[0 0 0]
     [0 1 2]               [1 1 1]
     [0 1 2]]              [2 2 2]]
```

but I'm new to Python and don't know how to produce a third grid of z values that looks like this:

```
z = [[Nan 15 Nan]
     [14  16  18]
     [17  Nan 13]]
```

Replacing `Nan` with `0` would be fine, too; my main problem is creating the 2D array in the first place. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I couldn't understand what is the expected functionality here.

Answer (score 35):

Assuming the `x` and `y` values in your file directly correspond to indices (as they do in your example), you can do something similar to this:

```
import numpy as np

x = [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2]
y = [1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2]
z = [14, 17, 15, 16, 18, 13]

z_array = np.nan * np.empty((3,3))
z_array[y, x] = z

print z_array
```

Which yields:

```
[[ nan  15.  nan]
 [ 14.  16.  18.]
 [ 17.  nan  13.]]
```

For large arrays, this will be much faster than the explicit loop over the coordinates.

---

### Dealing with non-uniform x & y input

If you have regularly sampled x & y points, then you can convert them to grid indices by subtracting the "corner" of your grid (i.e. `x0` and `y0`), dividing by the cell spacing, and casting as ints.  You can then use the method above or in any of the other answers.

As a general example:

```
i = ((y - y0) / dy).astype(int)
j = ((x - x0) / dx).astype(int)

grid[i,j] = z
```

However, there are a couple of tricks you can use if your data is not regularly spaced.

Let's say that we have the following data:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(1977)
x, y, z = np.random.random((3, 10))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
scat = ax.scatter(x, y, c=z, s=200)
fig.colorbar(scat)
ax.margins(0.05)
```

[image]

That we want to put into a regular 10x10 grid:

[image]

We can actually use/abuse `np.histogram2d` for this.  Instead of counts, we'll have it add the value of each point that falls into a cell.  It's easiest to do this through specifying `weights=z, normed=False`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(1977)
x, y, z = np.random.random((3, 10))

# Bin the data onto a 10x10 grid
# Have to reverse x & y due to row-first indexing
zi, yi, xi = np.histogram2d(y, x, bins=(10,10), weights=z, normed=False)
zi = np.ma.masked_equal(zi, 0)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.pcolormesh(xi, yi, zi, edgecolors='black')
scat = ax.scatter(x, y, c=z, s=200)
fig.colorbar(scat)
ax.margins(0.05)

plt.show()
```

[image]

However, if we have a large number of points, some bins will have more than one point.   The `weights` argument to `np.histogram` simply *adds* the values.  That's probably not what you want in this case.  Nonetheless, we can get the mean of the points that fall in each cell by dividing by the counts.

So, for example, let's say we have 50 points:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(1977)
x, y, z = np.random.random((3, 50))

# Bin the data onto a 10x10 grid
# Have to reverse x & y due to row-first indexing
zi, yi, xi = np.histogram2d(y, x, bins=(10,10), weights=z, normed=False)
counts, _, _ = np.histogram2d(y, x, bins=(10,10))

zi = zi / counts
zi = np.ma.masked_invalid(zi)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.pcolormesh(xi, yi, zi, edgecolors='black')
scat = ax.scatter(x, y, c=z, s=200)
fig.colorbar(scat)
ax.margins(0.05)

plt.show()
```

[image]

With very large numbers of points, this exact method will become slow (and can be sped up easily), but it's sufficient for anything less than ~1e6 points.

Comment: Unfortunately my `x` and `y` values don't actually correspond to indices. I suppose that was a poor choice of example! Instead they're a bit random, like `27 31 14` for my first row in the file.

Comment: If x and y are not indices how is the 2d array of z values defined?

Comment: @Dave - You have to define the extents and cellsize of the grid externally.  In this example, it's the min/max of the data with a 10x10 grid in between. However, this type of "binning" data is very often used for later discrete analysis.  In that case, you'll bin the data onto some pre-existing grid or bin it onto the grid that you'll be using for the rest of the analysis.

Comment: @JoeKington: excellent answer, I liked the histogram method. Is there a similar trick in case of n-dimensional data?

Comment: @Mannaggia - You can use the same trick with `np.histogramdd` for the n-dimensional case, as far as I know.  Be aware of the earlier caveat about speed, though.  It may be slower with high-dimensional datasets.

Comment: @JoeKington Hi, can you please help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45200428/how-to-find-intersection-of-a-line-with-a-mesh I am hoping to use np.meshgrid() function and scipy.interpolate.griddata() so that I could identify each cell with(i,j) coordinate and each segment in a cell can have some unique id

Answer (score 4):

You could try something like:

```python
import numpy as np

x = [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2]
y = [1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2]
z = [14, 17, 15, 16, 18, 13]

arr = np.zeros((3,3))
yx = zip(y,x)

for i, coord in enumerate(yx):
    arr[coord] = z[i]

print arr
>>> [[  0.  15.   0.]
     [ 14.  16.  18.]
     [ 17.   0.  13.]]
```

Comment: `arr[coord[0], coord[1]]` is a better way of indexing a 2d array.

Comment: Or even arr[coord] as with @Dave's answer

Answer (score 4):

Kezzos beat me to it but I had a similar approach,

```
x = np.array([0,0,1,1,2,2])
y = np.array([1,2,0,1,1,2])
z = np.array([14,17,15,16,18,13])
Z = np.zeros((3,3))
for i,j in enumerate(zip(x,y)): 
    Z[j] = z[i]

Z[np.where(Z==0)] = np.nan
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have `scipy` installed, you could take advantage of its `sparse` matrix module.  Get the values from the text file with `genfromtxt`, and plug those 'columns' directly into a `sparse` matrix creator.

```
In [545]: txt=b"""x y z
0 1 14
0 2 17
1 0 15
1 1 16
2 1 18
2 2 13
"""

In [546]: xyz=np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(),names=True,dtype=int)

In [547]: sparse.coo_matrix((xyz['z'],(xyz['y'],xyz['x']))).A     
Out[547]: 
array([[ 0, 15,  0],
       [14, 16, 18],
       [17,  0, 13]])
```

But Joe's `z_array=np.zeros((3,3),int); z_array[xyz['y'],xyz['x']]=xyz['z']` is considerably faster.

Answer (score 0):

Nice answers by others. Thought this might be a useful snippet for someone else who might need this.

```
def make_grid(x, y, z):
    '''
    Takes x, y, z values as lists and returns a 2D numpy array
    '''
    dx = abs(np.sort(list(set(x)))[1] - np.sort(list(set(x)))[0])
    dy = abs(np.sort(list(set(y)))[1] - np.sort(list(set(y)))[0])
    i = ((x - min(x)) / dx).astype(int) # Longitudes
    j = ((y - max(y)) / dy).astype(int) # Latitudes
    grid = np.nan * np.empty((len(set(j)),len(set(i))))
    grid[-j, i] = z # if using latitude and longitude (for WGS/West)
    return grid
```