# Python: How to plot heat map of 2D matrix by ignoring zeros?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, heatmap, colormap

I have a matrix of size 500 X 28000, which contains a lot of zeros in between. But let us consider a working example with the matrix A:

```
A = [[0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    [1, 0, 0, 2, 3],
    [5, 3, 0, 0, 0],
    [5, 0, 1, 0, 3],
    [6, 0, 0, 9, 0]]
```

I would like to plot a heatmap of the above matrix, but since it contains a lot of zeros, the heatmap contains almost white space as seen in the figure below.

**How can I ignore the zeros in the matrix and plot the heatmap?**

Here is the minimal working example that I tried:

```
im = plt.matshow(A, cmap=pl.cm.hot, norm=LogNorm(vmin=0.01, vmax=64), aspect='auto') # pl is pylab imported a pl
plt.colorbar(im)
plt.show()
```

which produces:

[image]

as you can see it is because of the zeros the white spaces appear.

But my original matrix of size 500X280000 contains a lot of zeros, which makes my colormap almost white!!

Comment: I am not convinced removing data just because the visualisation isn't clear is ever the right course of action. Have you considered grouping the data, or looking for a different type of plot? It might help if you could tell us more about the nature of the data you are working with.

Comment: I could not think of anything else other than a colorplot to visually represent my data. If there is any other way of representing it, do let me know.

Comment: You could try to use hierarchical clustering before plotting the heatmap.

Comment: @GWW Could you explain bit more ?

Comment: `norm=np.LogNorm(vmin=0.01, vmax=64)`. Where do you get LogNorm from? If you remove it, you get black colors for the zeroes instead. Why are you using a logarithmic scale? Is it needed? Because of log 0, I mean...

Comment: What do you mean exactly by 'ignoring'? Are you saying that the non-zero elements are so rare and are not visible because one element does not even occupy a single pixel for the 500x280000 data set? If so, how about plotting a fixed-size marker at the positions of non-zero elements, having readers understand that the values of the other elements not at the center of the markers are all zero?

Comment: @norio: yes the non-zero elements are rare in each array. Could you please elaborate on the `plotting a fixed-size marker at the positions of non-zero elements` as to how I can achieve it.

Comment: O.K. Instead of `matshow`, how about using, for example, `plot(idxrow, idxcol, mfc=color_valmat, mec=color_valmat, markersize=10)`, where `idxrow` and `idxcol` are vectors of 140,000,000(=500*280000) elements, containing the indices of the row and column, respectively, of all the matrix elements, and `color_valmat` is the color representing the value of the matrix elements. It's a bit difficult to explain by words. Does it make sense to you?

Comment: Since I have 500 rows and 28000 columns, how do I `plt.(row,column)` as it might say the dimensions are not the same. What do you mean by indices of the row and columns of the matrix?

Comment: I mean that we consider your matrix `A` as a data set of 140,000,000(=500*280000) elements. Each element has the attributes of row index, column index, and value. In other wors, we consider, conceptually (I'm not saying we do this in a python code), a data of `ds = {A[0,0], A[0,1], .., A[0,279999], A[1,0], A[1,1], .., A[1,279999], ..., A[499, 279999]}`. The k-th element of `ds` corresponds to `A[i,j]` with some `i` and `j`. Then, the 'row index' of `ds[k]` is `i`, the 'column index' of `ds[k]` is `j`, and the value of `ds[k]` is `A[i,j]`. The `0<=row_index[k]<500`, but `0<=k<140,000,000`.

Comment: Can you please post your above comment as the answer for my example matrix `A`? I can very much understand your `ds`, but still not completely the row index and column index in plotting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is in the same direction as 'Edit 2' section of Luis' answer. In fact, this is a simplified version of it. I am posting this just in order to correct my misleading statements in my comments. I saw a warning that we should not discuss in the comment area, so I am using this answering area.

Anyway, first let me post my code. Please note that I used a larger matrix randomly generated inside the script, instead of your sample matrix `A`.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#
# This script was written by norio 2016-8-5.

import os, re, sys, random
import numpy as np

#from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as img

mpl.rcParams['lines.linewidth'] = 2
mpl.rcParams['lines.markeredgewidth'] = 1.0
mpl.rcParams['axes.formatter.limits'] = (-4,4)
#mpl.rcParams['axes.formatter.limits'] = (-2,2)
mpl.rcParams['axes.labelsize'] = 'large'
mpl.rcParams['xtick.labelsize'] = 'large'
mpl.rcParams['ytick.labelsize'] = 'large'
mpl.rcParams['xtick.direction'] = 'out'
mpl.rcParams['ytick.direction'] = 'out'


############################################
#numrow=500
#numcol=280000
numrow=50
numcol=28000
# .. for testing
numelm=numrow*numcol
eps=1.0e-9
#
#numnz=int(1.0e-7*numelm)
numnz=int(1.0e-5*numelm)
# .. for testing
vmin=1.0e-6
vmax=1.0
outfigname='stackoverflow38790536.png'
############################################

### data matrix
# I am generating a data matrix here artificially.
print 'generating pseudo-data..'
random.seed('20160805')
matA=np.zeros((numrow, numcol))
for je in range(numnz):
    jr = random.uniform(0,numrow)
    jc = random.uniform(0,numcol)
    matA[jr,jc] = random.uniform(vmin,vmax)


### Actual processing for a given data will start from here
print 'processing..'

idxrow=[]
idxcol=[]
val=[]
for ii in range(numrow):
    for jj in range(numcol):
        if np.abs(matA[ii,jj])>eps:
            idxrow.append(ii)
            idxcol.append(jj)
            val.append( np.abs(matA[ii,jj]) )

print 'len(idxrow)=', len(idxrow)    
print 'len(idxcol)=', len(idxcol)    
print 'len(val)=',    len(val)    


############################################
# canvas setting for line plots 
############################################

f_size   = (8,5)

a1_left   = 0.15
a1_bottom  = 0.15
a1_width  = 0.65
a1_height = 0.80
#
hspace=0.02
#
ac_left   = a1_left+a1_width+hspace
ac_bottom = a1_bottom
ac_width  = 0.03
ac_height = a1_height

############################################
# plot 
############################################
print 'plotting..'

fig1=plt.figure(figsize=f_size)
ax1 =plt.axes([a1_left, a1_bottom, a1_width, a1_height], axisbg='w')

pc1=plt.scatter(idxcol, idxrow, s=20, c=val, cmap=mpl.cm.gist_heat_r)
# cf.
# http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter
plt.xlabel('Column Index', fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel('Row Index', fontsize=18)
ax1.set_xlim([0, numcol-1])
ax1.set_ylim([0, numrow-1])

axc =plt.axes([ac_left, ac_bottom, ac_width, ac_height], axisbg='w')
mpl.colorbar.Colorbar(axc,pc1, ticks=np.arange(0.0, 1.5, 0.1) )

plt.savefig(outfigname)
plt.close()
```

This script output a figure, 'stackoverflow38790536.png', which will look like the following.
[image: scatter plot of non-zero elements]

As you can see in my code, I used `scatter` instead of `plot`. I realized that the `plot` command is not best suitable for the task here.

Another of my words that I need to correct is that the `row_index` does not need to have as much as 140,000,000(=500*280000) elements. It only need to have the row indices of the non-zero elements. More correctly, the lists,
`idxrow`, `idxcol`, and `val`, which enter into `scatter` command in the code above, has the lengths equal to the number of non-zero elements.

Please note that both of these points have been correctly taken care of in Luis' answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you remove the LogNorm, you get black squares instead of white:

```
im = plt.matshow(A, cmap=plt.cm.hot, aspect='auto') # pl is pylab imported a pl
```

[image]

---

**Edit**

In a colormap you *always* have the complete grid filled with values. That's why you actually create the grid: You account for (say: interpolate) all the points that are not exactly in the grid. That means that your data **has** many zeroes and that the graph correctly reflects that by looking white (or black). By ignoring those values, you create a misleading graph, if you don't have a clear reason to do so.

If the values different than zero are the ones of interest to you, then you need another type of diagram, like pointed out by [norio's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38790536/python-how-to-plot-heat-map-of-2d-matrix-by-ignoring-zeros/38790834?noredirect=1#comment64952253_38790536). For that, you may want to have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30765484/776515).

---

**Edit 2**

> Adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30765484/776515)

You can treat the values as 1D arrays and plot the points independently, instead of filling a mesh with non-desired values.

```
A = [[0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    [1, 0, 0, 2, 3],
    [5, 3, 0, 0, 0],
    [5, 0, 1, 0, 3],
    [6, 0, 0, 9, 0]]
A = np.array(A)
lenx, leny = A.shape

xx = np.array( [ a for a in range(lenx) for a in range(leny) ] )   # Convert 3D to 3*1D
yy = np.array( [ a for a in range(lenx) for b in range(leny) ] )
zz = np.array( [ A[x][y] for x,y in zip(xx,yy) ] )
#---
xx = xx[zz!=0]    # Drop zeroes
yy = yy[zz!=0]
zz = zz[zz!=0]
#---
zi, yi, xi = np.histogram2d(yy, xx, bins=(10,10), weights=zz, normed=False)
zi = np.ma.masked_equal(zi, 0)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.pcolormesh(xi, yi, zi, edgecolors='black')
scat = ax.scatter(xx, yy, c=zz, s=200)
fig.colorbar(scat)
ax.margins(0.05)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The OP is asking to remove the contribution of zeros itself, here you still have it shown by black.

Comment: @Luis. Yes I tried it before posting here. Still I am not able to visualise the the heatmap since my matrix really big. It shows a  black figure with little red dots.

Comment: The thing is, by definition, in a color map you have a complete grid, where **all** points will be plotted. If this is not the case, you need another type of plot. See norio's comment above.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the zeroes to `float("nan")` and plot after that, works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Although the answer of norio is correct. I think one can give a much more to the point quick answer with only a few lines of code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
A = np.asarray(A)
x,y = A.nonzero() #get the notzero indices
plt.scatter(x,y,c=A[x,y],s=100,cmap='hot',marker='s') #adjust the size to your needs
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Note that the axis are inverted. you could invert them by:

```
ax=plt.gca()
ax.invert_xaxis()
ax.invert_yaxis()
```

Also note that you have much more flexibility now:

- You can set the marker-size and the marker-type and transparancy optionally
- This procedure is faster, as the zeros are not parsed to matplotlib.